# $ionicHistory.goBack() is not a function

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

```
$scope.goBack = function (){
            //$ionicHistory.goBack(): It's doesn't work
           // window.history.back();  It's ok
        };
```

Why?

I am a novice.Is there anyone who can help me ?

Comment: Did you add `$ionicHistory` as dependency ?

Comment: hey,sorry,
it is ["$scope","$ionicHistory","$state",function($scope,$ionicHist‌​ory,$state){}]). 

$ionicHistory  must be  in front of $state,and it's work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from a similar question in the ionic forum

[Read here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionichistory-goback-not-working/31538/4)

> Do you use left menu in your application? If true you may notice that directive menu-close will close menu and clear your history. Use menu-toggle instead of menu-close.

Comment: Could you please post how you solved it so other's in a similar situation might know?

Comment: My English is so bad, I don't know if you can understand it.

before:

` .controller("tabs-iMeeting",["$state","$ionicHistory",function($scope,$ionicHistory){}])`

now:

` .controller("tabs-iMeeting",function($scope,$ionicHistory,$location,$state,$ionicModal){}`

But,I dont konw why...

Comment: One problem i can see is that the dependencies in the array dont match the ones in the function. So, 
your before should have been ['$state','$ionicHistory', function($state, $ionicHistory)....

The order must match

Comment: hey,sorry,
it is ["$scope","$ionicHistory","$state",function($scope,$ionicHist‌​ory,$state){}]). 

$ionicHistory  must be  in front of $state,and it's work